# Product.JSON is not loading in angular2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Im loading the Product.json file in angular2 application.

### Please find code of my application below, Suggest

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule ({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule,HttpModule],
   declarations: [ AppComponent],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './products.service';
import { appService } from './app.service';
import { Http , Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component ({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: '<div>Hello</div>',
   providers: [ProductService]
})

export   class   AppComponent  {
   iproducts: IProduct[];
   constructor(private _product: ProductService) {
   }

   ngOnInit() : void {
      this._product.getproducts()
      .subscribe(iproducts => this.iproducts = iproducts);
   }
}
```

---

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demoproject</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Products.json

```
[{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "ProductA"
},

{
   "ProductID": 2,
   "ProductName": "ProductB"
}]
```

---

products.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
   private _producturl='app/products.json';
   constructor(private _http: Http){}

   getproducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
      return this._http.get(this._producturl)
      .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
      .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
   }
```

### }

product.ts

```
export interface IProduct {
   ProductID: number;
   ProductName: string;
}
```

It gives me error in console section product.json file not found(404).

any one please suggest. im new in angular2

Comment: Using angular cli? then place the json file in your `assets` folder and call `assets/products.json`

Comment: Thanks @Alex its working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `export` the data from `Products.json`

```
export const productData : IProduct = [{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "ProductA"
},

{
   "ProductID": 2,
   "ProductName": "ProductB"
}]
```

OR

Just put that file within `assets` folder and access it.

For more detail : **[READ](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79)**

Comment: We need to add all the files by putting in assets folder only???? if i need to add css or js file in my anglar 2 application then how to add it

Comment: You can keep the .json file withing application folder but then you need to do it as I explained , using export .

Comment: All those file should be in assets folder